# Wordpress only loads one script from the public function enqueue_scripts() {

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate)

In the plugins class-my-plugin-public.php I have the enqueue_scripts() function.

The ajax and the fabric load just fine.  However if I load others below it will not insert into the page.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
/**
 * Register the JavaScript for the public-facing side of the site.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function enqueue_scripts() {


    wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'canvas-draw' , array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/fabric.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );

    // This doesnt load
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/scroll-behaviour.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, true );
    // This doesnt load either
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/drag-drop-index.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, true );



}
```

Comment: Where do you specify the unique $handle as per - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ - it appears like you are trying to reuse `$this->plugin_name` - here's the note from link above - If you try to register or enqueue an already registered handle with different parameters, the new parameters will be ignored. Instead, use wp_deregister_script() and register the script again with the new parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have unique **$handle** name for each script that you enqueue.

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

> $handle
>   (string) (Required) Name of the script. Should be unique.

You can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Register the JavaScript for the public-facing side of the site.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function enqueue_scripts() {


    wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'canvas-draw' , array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '_fabric', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/fabric.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '_scroll-behaviour', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/scroll-behaviour.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '_drag-drop-index', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/drag-drop-index.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, true );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a closing body tage `</body>` it might be the problem since wp appends the script just before it